# Issue with ANTlr4 <EOF> when <EOF> is reached from inside a custom MODE

Tags: antlr4

I have a few different modes in my grammar and have found that if `<EOF>` is reached whilst inside one of these modes, the current text is incorporated inside the `<EOF>` token.

For example, if I pass a malformed expression such as **top hat" tails** through the grammar, I get `WORD` `WORD` `<EOF>` instead of `WORD` `WORD` `QUOTE` `IN_QUOTE` `<EOF>`

> ```
> ctx = {org.epo.presto.pql.grammar.PQL$ParseContext@520}"[]"
>  children = {java.util.ArrayList@869} size = 2
>   [0] = {org.epo.presto.pql.grammar.PQL$ProximityExpressionContext@1022}"[24]"
>    _p = 0
>    children = {java.util.ArrayList@1033} size = 2
>    start = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken@881}"[@0,0:2='top',<34>,1:0]"
>    stop = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken@882}"[@1,4:7='hat',<34>,1:4]"
>    altNum = 0
>    exception = null
>    parent = {org.epo.presto.pql.grammar.PQL$ParseContext@520}"[]"
>    invokingState = 24
>   [1] = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.TerminalNodeImpl@1023}"<EOF>"
>    symbol = {org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken@1028}"[@2,8:14='\" tails',<-1>,1:8]"
>    parent = {org.epo.presto.pql.grammar.PQL$ParseContext@520}"[]"
> ```

The relevant sections of my grammar are:

```
QUOTE           : '"' -> more, pushMode(QUOTED);
OTHER           : ~[\{\}()!,./:|\[\] "=<>\~$];
WORD            : OTHER+;

mode QUOTED;
QUOTATION       : '"' -> popMode;
IN_QUOTE        : ~["] -> more;
```

Is there a preferred way for dealing with `<EOF>` within modes?

I have tried this with both the ANTlr 4 release and the todays master from github and get the same result.

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `more` command instructs the lexer to not issue "partial" tokens. Instead of giving you `QUOTE`, `IN_QUOTE`, and `QUOTATION` tokens, the `QUOTE` and `IN_QUOTE` parts will always be merged with the following token, leaving you with a single `QUOTATION` token or none at all.

You have at least two options for dealing with this situation.

1. Remove the `more` commands and handle `QUOTE`, `IN_QUOTE`, and `QUOTATION` separately in your parser.
2. Leave the `more` commands in place and add the following rule to your lexer after the `IN_QUOTE` token. For your input, this would produce the tokens `WORD` `WORD` `INCOMPLETE_QUOTE`.

   ```
   INCOMPLETE_QUOTE
       :   EOF -> popMode
       ;
   ```